# What is the 1750Hz tone burst for?

Tags: icom, europe

The Icom IC-51E PLUS2 but not the American version will emit a 1750Hz tone burst when you push the PTT briefly and then hold it down.

What is this for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1750 tone burst is widely used in European the same way that CTCSS/PL and DCS is used for repeater access in the US. I used tone burst exclusively when living in Germany. Tone burst never caught on in the US.